# How to batch update using jooq

Tags: java, jooq

Using the following way to update using jOOQ.

```
for (Balance balance : balances) {
       dslContext.update(BALANCE)
                 .set(BALANCE.AMOUNT, balance.getAmount())
                 .where(BALANCE.ID.eq(balance.getId))
                 .execute();
}
```

This iterates over all balances and insert each. I know this can be done using UpdatableRecord. But
i want to avoid fetching balance from database. Balance is table with more than 8 fields, but i am interested in updating only one field.Is there any other way to do this without UpdatableRecord?

Comment: Where do your `(id, amount)` pairs come from?

Comment: i receive list of balances from an external service. so for this method it is through method arguments

Answer (score 15):

#### A batch statement using `UpdatableRecord`

You can still use `UpdatableRecord` if you want the convenience of [`DSLContext.batchUpdate()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchUpdate(org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...)), without fetching all the records from the database first. Assuming you're using the code generator and you're generating records, you'll have `BalanceRecord`:

```java
ctx.batchUpdate(balances
   .stream()
   .map(b -> { 
       var r = new BalanceRecord();
       r.setAmount(b.getAmount());
       r.setId(b.getId());
       r.changed(BALANCE.ID, false); // Prevent setting the ID to itself
       return r;
   })
   .collect(toList()))
   .execute();
```

This will create a [batch statement](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/) behind the scenes for you.

#### Using a `BatchedConnection`

Starting with jOOQ 3.14, you can transparently batch all of your logic using a [`BatchedConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batched-connection/), which is a special JDBC connection proxy that delays the execution of all your JDBC statements (jOOQ created or not), buffering them until an execution is required:

```java
dslContext.batched(c -> {
    for (Balance balance : balances) {
        c.dsl().update(BALANCE)
               .set(BALANCE.AMOUNT, balance.getAmount())
               .where(BALANCE.ID.eq(balance.getId))
               .execute(); // This doesn't execute the query yet
    }
} // Now, the buffered queries are being batch-executed
```

#### Running a single bulk statement

From your comments, there seems to be a desire to run this as a single *bulk statement*, instead of batching multiple statements in a single *batch statement* (single round trip).

I'm not convinced this is the right approach - the statement can get huge and is not necessarily faster than the batch, but of course, you can do this using a [`CASE` expression](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/)

```java
ctx.update(BALANCE)
   .set(BALANCE.AMOUNT, 
     case_(BALANCE.ID).mapValues(
       balances.stream().collect(toMap(balance::getId, balance::getValue))
     )
   )
   .where(BALANCE.ID.in(balances.stream().map(balance::getId).collect(toList())))
   .execute();
```

This will produce something like:

```sql
UPDATE balance
SET amount = 
  CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 2.50
    WHEN 2 THEN 3.50
    WHEN 13 THEN 8.30
  END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 13)
```

Depending on the dialect you're using, this might be better done with `MERGE`:

```sql
MERGE INTO balance
USING (
  VALUES (1, 2.50), (2, 3.50), (13, 8.30)
) AS s (i, b)
ON balance.id = s.i 
AND balance.balance = s.b
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET balance = b
```

Comment: can you also provide an example of using it with MERGE statement/onDuplicateKeyUpdate?

Comment: `DSLContext.batchMerge()` has been added only in jOOQ 3.14 (not yet published as of now). You would just change the `batchUpdate()` call to `batchMerge()`

Comment: above code generates query which will consider only id in where clause for update. How can i add more conditions in where clause ?

Comment: @pppavan: You write an explicit query as suggested by [Simon Martinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62870698/521799), but using the [syntax suggested in the manual for bind variable usage](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/)

Comment: above query doesnt generate a batch update but instead generates many update queries. Does batchUpdate work similar to batchInsert as reported https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4533

Comment: @pppavan: That depends on what you think "batch" means. jOOQ uses "batch" in the same way as JDBC, as in "sending a batch of statements to the server". Do you mean "bulk" update?

Comment: yes bulk update.. i tried using bind variables . But there are multiple update queries instead of one with bind variables.

Comment: Thanks. I did test for update using bind variables and using UpdatableRecord.And bind variables performs 10 times better than  UpdatableRecord. Is it expected behaviour ?

Comment: @LukasEder How about if I want  use the first way with  var r = new BalanceRecord(), but i don't have ID, and i want use for condition another field?

Comment: @MaximBezmen: Sounds like a new question, not something I could explain reasonably within the limits of Stack Overflow's comments feature...

Comment: @LukasEder https://stackoverflow.com/q/73150064/14756421

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine but you could use the batch updates like this:

```
List<UpdateConditionStep<BalanceRecord> updates = new ArrayList<>();
for (Balance balance : balances) {
   updates.add(dslContext.update(BALANCE)
             .set(BALANCE.AMOUNT, balance.getAmount())
             .where(BALANCE.ID.eq(balance.getId)));
}

dslContext.batch(updates).execute();
```

Documentation: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual-single-page/#batch-execution

Just a hint: Be careful of lost updates if you update a balance without locking.

Comment: looks like it doesnt use bind values?

Comment: No? How does the executed SQL look like?

Comment: This corresponds to batching several statements that aren't necessarily related. With JDBC, this cannot be done using bind variables. What you're looking for is to batch a single query and provide a bind variable set using `bind(...)`, on the same page: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/