# How to batch update using jooq without id

Tags: jooq

```
create.batchUpdate(gameOrders
    .stream()
    .map(x -> {
      var game = new GameRecord();
      game.setOrder(x.newOrder());
      game.setId(x.id()); <------- this 
      // Prevent setting the ID to itself
      game.changed(GAME.ID, false);
      return game;
    })
    .toList())
  .executeAsync();
```

It is works fine. Because in this case I'm using id (PK)

```
create.batchUpdate(gameOrders
        .stream()
        .map(x -> {
          var game = new GameRecord();
          game.setOrder(x.newOrder());
          game.setName(x.newOrder());
          // Prevent setting the NAME to itself
          game.changed(GAME.NAME, false);
          return game;
        })
        .toList())
      .executeAsync();
```

I want to do it, but nothing won't update in DB, because in this case I don't use id only newOrder and newOrder.

How I can use this way for batchUpdate, if I don't have ID (PK)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the statements "I don't have ID" (but then, why are you setting it?) and "I want to use another field for the condition" (you mean that you want to update things based on some non-ID predicate? Can you show what *exactly* you want to do in code?

Comment: @LukasEder the question was update

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what it is you're trying to do. Can you please review this useful resource, and possibly try again? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for the complicated explanation. I just want to do a batch update in the above way, however, I don’t get the PK (ID) for each record in list, although in fact it is present in the table

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do an `UPDATE` based on an `UpdatableRecord`, which *always* performs its work based on the primary key. But apparently, that's not what you want to do. You want to run something like this:

```sql
UPDATE game
SET
  order = ?,
  name = ?
WHERE something = ?
```

So, why not just write an `UPDATE` statement instead, with jOOQ?

```java
ctx.update(GAME)
   .set(GAME.ORDER, order)
   .set(GAME.NAME, name)
   .where(GAME.SOMETHING.eq(something))
   .execute();
```

Updates can be batched as well, see

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batched-connection/

You don't *have to* do this with `UpdatableRecord` API

Comment: Okay,You got it right. Thank you for the clarification.