# Jooq update table records without primary key unexpectedly inserts new records

Tags: mariadb, jooq

I have a table called result that has no primary key (cannot change that). I want to update all the records that meet a certain condition using Jooq. The following code doesn't work as I expected. It inserts new records instead of updating existing ones, which I don't understand.

```
public Mono<Result> update(Result result, String name) {
        return Mono.from(ctx.update(RESULT)
                        .set(RESULT.STATUS, result.getStatus())
                        .where(RESULT.NAME.eq(name))
                        .returning()
                )
                .map(r -> r.into(Result.class));
```

Comment: I didn't simplify my example, this is actually the code that I have. It is actually just inserting new records instead of updating the existing ones. At first I thought it had to do with the table not having a primary key, but then I saw this post and I realised that my example should be working 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150064/how-to-batch-update-using-jooq-without-id

Comment: @LukasEder well I just discovered why. I reworked the code and tried with a table with a primary key(I added just an autoincrement id as primary key) and another table without a primary key. If the table has a primary key, it works. If not, it inserts as many records as it is supposed to update. It's not me inventing stuff. I must say that the rest of the code is pretty huge, so I will try to do as you say and make a small example when I have time. Still, if you all say that there is nothing wrong with that code and should be working, then this has to be a bug.

Comment: @LukasEder forgot to mention, about what was being inserted, well, the first record that was supposed to be updated is reinserted as many times as the .where(RESULT.NAME.eq(name)) is true. This made my table which contained around 10 records to finish with hundred of records after just a couple of calls of the update function.

Comment: My apologies. I had overlooked the `returning()` method, and that this was a MariaDB question, earlier :( MariaDB doesn't have native support for [`UPDATE .. RETURNING`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/), so jOOQ runs an `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement on the data that is matched by the `WHERE` clause, the assumption being that there's indeed a primary key.

Comment: @LukasEder I understand, thanks. How should I approach this then if I have no primary key?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why a table that is updatable wouldn't have a primary key?

Comment: Its just a series of info entries that can have repeated information in their fields without anything that can remotely be used as a primary key. Once a new entry comes meeting a certain condition, all the already existing meeting the same condition have to have a field updated. I guess it's a weird use case.

Comment: I mean, I've always regretted any table without primary key, even if it was just a surrogate key. Maybe, you'll still add one? I don't think the `UPDATE .. RETURNING` statement can be emulated in a straightforward way, otherwise. See the discussion for MySQL here, which doesn't support `RETURNING` on `INSERT` either: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6865. I'd just add the surrogate key.

Sorry again for the confusion earlier. It does look very weird indeed when records are inserted in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @LukasEder ok, just wanted to know if there could be a way. I understand that I will need to add a primary key. No worries about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ 3.18 introduced an emulation for `UPDATE .. RETURNING` in MariaDB 10.5, which doesn't support this syntax natively:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13928

In short, this kind of statement:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET a = b
WHERE p
ORDER BY o
LIMIT l
RETURNING x;
```

Can be emulated as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO t
SELECT * FROM t WHERE p ORDER BY o LIMIT l
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET a = b
RETURNING x;
```

But obviously, this assumes the presence of a primary key (or unique key) which can be matched by the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause. In other words, jOOQ can emulate `UPDATE .. RETURNING` *only* if you have some unique constraint, not otherwise.

It is debatable whether this requirement should be indicated to the user in form of an error:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15582